# CSS viewport scale if less than 375px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a responsive website with bootstrap and we got as target smaller phone iPhone 6, we can't reduce all the elements to fit in iPhone SE or 4" phones

I would like to know if I can edit viewport in such a way that under iPhone 6 ( 375px ) resolution web page will scale as a non responsive website with the xs view.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: You mean, act as if there were no "viewport" meta when on such small screens?

Comment: all the css in Bootstrap takes care of ,most of it but you can add some custom css to certain parts

Comment: I would like to resize the XS view when going lower than 375px, like proportionally shrink the all thing.